# Spark only runs my app with a single task

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I wrote a simple Spark application on top of AWS EMR 6.4.0 that basically does this:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyAppName").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaRDD<String> dataSet = javaSparkContext.parallelize(_a_list_with_100_elements_);
// here I also tried to force 100 slices with .parallelize(_a_list_with_100_elements_, 100)

long count = dataSet.flatMap(....)
    .flatMap(...)
    .map(_something_that_outputs_0_or_1)
    .reduce(Integer::sum);

javaSparkContext.stop();
```

I'm running the app using the following command:

```
aws emr add-steps --profile myprofile --region us-east-1 --cluster-id j-SOMEID --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=test-downloader,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=command-runner.jar,Args=spark-submit,--class,com.my.main.MyClass,s3://somebucket/my.packaged.app-1.0.jar,-arg1,some,more,cli,args
```

But both locally or in a cluster with 10 hosts, I see only logs like this:

```
20:20:21.354 [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)] INFO  some log from my flatMap with element 0 from the list
20:20:21.789 [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)] INFO  some log from my flatMap with element 0 from the list
20:20:22.354 [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)] INFO  some log from my map with element 0 from the list
20:20:22.678 [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)] INFO  some log from my flatMap with element 1 from the list
20:20:23.975 [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)] INFO  some log from my flatMap with element 1 from the list
20:20:24.354 [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)] INFO  some log from my map with element 1 from the list
[...] more logs with the other elements, consecutively
```

I see always the task 0 in the logs and the application is running slowly like it runs a single task even though I have 10 machines in the cluster.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it run more stuff in parallel? Each map or flatMap returns one or more elements, so it's not like it's running out of stuff to do (except the last map that's actually downloading something and return 0 or 1 depending if it succeeded or not).

Answer (score 0):

For AWS EMR you should use "yarn" as the master. There is more info on what this means, here:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

So the line used to start your EMR step would look like this:

```
aws emr add-steps --profile yourProfile --region your_region --cluster-id CLUSTER_ID --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=test-java,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=command-runner.jar,Args=spark-submit,--class,com.your.MyClass,--master,yarn,--deploy-mode,client,s3://your_bucket/your_jar.jar,...application_params...
```